# Schema for appointment booking system using MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a doctor appointment booking system for a single doctor using MySql.

A patient will have to select a date and choose a time-slot .Each hour should be divided into 6 slots Each slot should have only 10 minutes to it.

Also a particular date and its slots can be locked if the doctor is busy on that particular day.

Please help me design a schema for the table in which a customer can book a slot .

Comment: Too broad for SO. You're asking us to design your system for you, not fix a problem with your code. There's a lot of work to do here, far more than is worth 15 reputation points. Also, only you know the full requirements in order to create design (I doubt what you have listed here constitutes _all_ the requirements, including non-functional ones). If you're unsure of the principles needed to design it correctly, go and study database normalisation and entity relationships. You need a strong understanding of these principles before you can begin.

Comment: P.S. If you're have no clue what to do, I'm sure someone here will be available for consultancy at the appropriate rate...get your credit card ready :-)